# Drupal Fivestar rating

Tags: rating

I have configured my node using Fivestar module such that user can vote on multiple parameters. For ex. The type of node is movie and user can vote the node based on Script, Acting, Story, Direction, Cinematography. All of this works fine and I am also able to calculate an average of all the fields using 'Computed Field'.

Now how can I make a user vote on all items in a group and not just individual ones in Drupal 7 ?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. Please read the FAQ (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq). Now what is your question?

Comment: While it could be phrased better, I believe the question is "How can I require a user to vote on all items in a group, not just individual ones?".

Comment: @Letharion Yes i am looking for the same.

Comment: I didn't say I was looking for the same thing, I was just trying to re-phrase your question. People are having issues understanding what you are after, and I would recommend you try to clarify your question or you risk having it closed.